# почему QByteArray выдает ошибку С2440?

Tags: c++, qt

Почему QByteArray выдает ошибку преобразования QСharRef в char (в инт тоже не хочет ) .

Как перевести char в QСharRef ?????

```
QFile file("izl_chanel.txt");
if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{

     QByteArray b ; 
     int K = 364 ;


    QTextStream stream(&file);
    QString str;
    while (!stream.atEnd())
    {
        str = stream.readLine();
        qDebug() << str;
        for (int i = 0; i<str.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(str[i] == '0')
            {
                // b.append(int (str[0]));
                b.append(str[0]);
            }
        }

    }
    if (stream.status() != QTextStream::Ok)
    {
        qDebug() << "Ошибка чтения файла";
    }
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что этот код делает то, что вам нужно? Потому как делает он какую-то фигню.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что должно каститься?

Comment: kff спасибо  !! :) Только как этим пользоваться ?? ;_;

Comment: `QByteArray b = str.toUtf8();`. Но мне кажется, что Вам нужен не `QTextStream`, а `QDataStream` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qdatastream.html).

Comment: QByteArray b = str.toUtf8(); куда это ставить ????